# PL/pgSQL vs Python

Tags: python, plpgsql

What is faster, a Python script or a PL/pgSQL procedure?

For instance, if I want to insert for each USER_NAME and USER_PERM from USERS into SYN_USER, I could use this procedure (minimal example):

```sql
...
BEGIN
    FOR my_user IN
       select USER_NAME, USER_PERM from USERS
    LOOP
        insert into SYN_USER(SUS_NAME,SUS_PERMS)
        VALUES (my_user.USER_NAME, ISNULL(my_user.USER_PERM,0));
    END LOOP;
END
```

I could also use Python like so:

```
...
results = SQL.fetch_all('select USER_NAME, USER_PERM from USERS')
query = "insert into SYN_USER(SUS_NAME,SUS_PERMS) VALUES "
for result in results:
    query += f"({result.USER_NAME}, {(result.USER_PERM if result.USER_PERM is not None else 0)}"
SQL.insert(query)
```

But which one would be faster?
Is there an absolute response like "... will always be faster" or does it depend on the kind of code like "... will be faster unless it have more than X lines"?

I tried to look online for a benchmark between PL/pgSQL and Python but it seems that no one is as stupid as me or has the exact same problem.

Comment: I would bet that the client based solution would be slower due to round trips, but you should test it if this is somehow critical.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Why would you use a loop for this? A single INSERT statement using a SELECT is good enough. You could wrap it in a function, but performance would be more or less equal. Loops are slow and using this pattern in an external client, python in your case, would make it even worse. You'd better use a set-based approach

Answer (score 2):

That depends on usage. PL/pgSQL is much deeper integrated with SQL engine, and use (by default) cached plans for embedded SQL. So repeated execution of SQL statements can be faster in PL/pgSQL (but usually bottleneck is in query execution (not in query planning), so there will not be significant difference between PL/pgSQL and PL/Pythonu.

PL/pgSQL translates expressions to SQL expressions, and execution is not extra fast. PL/Pythonu executes expressions directly, and it should be significantly faster than PL/pgSQL. When your code has some parts with heavy numeric calculations (or string operations), then Python should be significantly faster. But the load and initialization of Python runtime is slower than initialization of PL/pgSQL - because PL/pgSQL is primitive and it is deeper integrated to Postgres. So execution of very short functions can be faster in PL/pgSQL.

PL/pgSQL is trusted language (any user can write functions) with possibility to directly write queries there (the code with lot of SQL is more readable, and SQL can be checked before execution). PL/Pythonu is untrusted language (only superuser can write functions), without integrated SQL (SQL is string), but it is generic language (XML or JSON processing is very simple there).

The usage of PL/Pythonu or PL/pgSQL doesn't depends on performance (usually), but depends on different functionality, scope or orientation.